searxng public instance giving too many requests
I am writing a python code for a college assignment and part of the code runs a query through google and returns the top 5 results. I want to change it so the query goes through a searxng public instance (I'm very new to searxng so I would prefer not to create a private instance and host it myself), However every time I try to use a public instance I keep getting error 403 too many requests.
I tried to limit the number of requests, add a delay but it didn't work. I found a single public instance but it uses searx not searxng and it doesn't return any results from google only from wikipedia and yahoo and sometimes bing (https://searx.thegpm.org/ this one). I would appreciate it if someone can help or at give a reference I can follow or do something similar to

The "too many requests" response comes from the bot blocker which is active on all public SearXNG instances.
You can run your own SearXNG instance on localhost. The following should be sufficient for a POC (quickstart guide):
$ git clone https://github.com/searxng/searxng.git searxng
$ cd searxng
$ make run

For a productive environment choose one of the installation methods.
